# Elastic Search: JSON to NEST query without duplicates

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

How to convert json query to nest query below and remove duplicates?

```
{
      "size": 30,
      "query": {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "london",
            "operator": "OR",
            "fields": [
            "name",
             "venueTown"
            ]
          }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the aggregations section a little and put the top hits in

```
var searchResult = client.Search<SearchResult>(request => request
    // Your existing query below...
    //.Query(q => q)
    .Size(0)
    .Aggregations(a => a
        // simplify the terms aggregation
        .Terms("query", tr => tr
            .Field("name")
            .Size(30)
        )
        // Add the top hits aggregation
        .TopHits("top", th => th
            .Size(1)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I dont get the response wanted, How can I input raw query into nest and then send it to Elastic Search?

Comment: @ProgLearner Yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40076192/1831 for options