# Serialising an object to JSON, and then using that to send a query in elastic search using NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, nosql

I get a bit confused and frustrated when it comes to using NEST to querying, as it seems very hit and miss. I have no trouble querying when using standard JSON, so I was wondering if there was some way to query using a JSON object, I have code below

```
var query = "bkala";

var q = new
{
    query = new
    {
        text = new
        {
            _all = "jane"
        }
    }
};

var qJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(q);
var hits = client.Search<Users>(qJson);
```

However, I get the error "Cannot convert from type string to System.Func, Nest.ISearchRequest"

If anyone knows how I can simply query using a JSON object, that would be fantastic, cheers in advance.

Comment: I don't have any experience with ElasticSearch, but I think you're using the API in wrong way. The search-method obviously takes a `Func<ISearchRequest>` whereas you're passing a `string`. Take a look at the docs here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/covariant-search-results.html#_using_types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NEST and Elasticsearch.Net, the low level client that NEST uses under the covers, are flexible in how you wish to query. With NEST you have a couple of different ways:

#### NEST - High level client

**1.Fluent API**

```
var query = "bkala";

var searchResult = client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field("_all")
            .Query(query)
        )
    )
);
```

Laid out as above, this API uses lambda expressions to define a fluent interface that mimics the structure of the Elasticsearch json API and query DSL.

**2.Object Initializer Syntax**

```
var query = "bkala";

var request = new SearchRequest<MyDocument>
{
    Query = new MatchQuery
    {   
        Field = "_all",
        Query = query
    }
};

var searchResult = client.Search<MyDocument>(request);
```

If lambda expressions are not your thing, then you can always define your searches using specific search types.

#### Elasticsearch.Net - Low level client

In cases where you would like to query with anonymous types (as per your question), json strings or a byte representation of a query, then you can use the low level client, Elasticsearch.Net, to achieve this. The low level client is exposed on the high level client through the `.LowLevel` property

**1.Anonymous types**

```
var query = new
{
    query = new
    {
        match = new
        {
            _all = new
            {
                query = "bkala"
            }
        }
    }
};

var searchResult = client.LowLevel.Search<SearchResponse<MyDocument>>(query);
```

Using the low level client on the high level client means that you can still take advantage of using Json.NET to deserialize search results; in this example, the search response can be accessed through `searchResult.Body`

**2.Json string**

```
var query = @"
{
  ""query"": {
    ""match"": {
      ""_all"": {
        ""query"": ""bkala""
      }
    }
  }
}";

var searchResult = client.LowLevel.Search<SearchResponse<MyDocument>>(query);
```

**3.Byte array**

```
var bytes = new byte[] { 123, 13, 10, 32, 32, 34, 113, 117, 101, 114, 121, 34, 58, 32, 123, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 109, 97, 116, 99, 104, 34, 58, 32, 123, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 95, 97, 108, 108, 34, 58, 32, 123, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 113, 117, 101, 114, 121, 34, 58, 32, 34, 98, 107, 97, 108, 97, 34, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 125, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 125, 13, 10, 32, 32, 125, 13, 10, 125 };

var searchResult = client.LowLevel.Search<SearchResponse<MyDocument>>(bytes);
```

All of the above methods produce the following query

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": {
        "query": "bkala"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Check out the [Getting started guide on the github repo](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net) as well as the [documentation on the Elastic website](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/index.html). We are continually working to improve documentation and PRs are more than welcome for areas where you feel we are lacking :)